# In SharePoint calculated column, Get Max(value) based on contents of other columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In a Sharepoint document library I need to get the max itemnumber+1 if type and role are equal to the value I'm using for a new document.

[image]

Type is a choice column with 10 choices;
Role is a choice column with 5 choices;
Itemnumber is a calculated column.

So if I set the column Type to A, and Role to D, then the value of Itemnumber = 2.
If I set the column Type to A, and Role to E, then the value of Itemnumber = 1 (as that combination is not there yet)

I've been trying things like this, bu can't get it to work:
=if(concatinate(FIND([type],[type]),FIND([role],[role])
)
)==concatinate([type],[role])

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use following formula in the calculated column.

=if(And([Type]="A",[Role]="D"),2,if(And([Type]="B",[Role]="E"),3,if(And([Type]="C",[Role]="F"),4,1)))

Comment: Very interesting statement which I've documented for future use! thanks.

It doesn't help to get that largest current value, but it could catagorize.

Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.